# Capybara feature tests does not commit database transactions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rspec, capybara

I am using Machinist to create my test users which I want to log in before each test which I am running with Capybara:

```
include Capybara::DSL
include ActionController::UrlWriter

before do
  SslRequirement.disable_ssl_check = true
  user = User.make


  visit new_user_session_path
  fill_in('username', with: user.email)
  fill_in('password', with: '12345')
  click_button('submit')
end

it "responds as expected" do
   # ...
end
```

Now when the user is created with `User.make` I can access it through `User.all` when it fact it's not persisted in the database yet, this is because

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.open_transactions == 1
```

I can fix/hack this by doing a

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.commit_db_transaction
```

after `User.make`, but I'd rather fix this properly. Is this a Capybara configuration which I am missing? Disclaimer: Using `Rails 2.3` and `RSpec 1.3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't show which driver you're using with Capybara, but generally you shouldn't be using transactions for testing when using Capybara (yes there are potential workarounds to allow it but they all have side-effects). See [transactions and database setup](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#transactions-and-database-setup) and then look into the database_cleaner gem with truncation  - here's a blog post about it that should be good with the age of gems you're using - http://devblog.avdi.org/2012/08/31/configuring-database_cleaner-with-rails-rspec-capybara-and-selenium/

Comment: As in, doing the whole setup beforehand somewhere else?

Comment: I added a link to a blog post about it that should be good for the age of rails and rspec you're using